# How to remove entire column from data frame if column name is nan, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data frame with 15 columns & some column name is nan, How to delete if column name is nan.

columns:

```
['Country', 'Survey', 'a typical day', 'a particularly good day',
   'a particularl', 'dk/refused', 'total', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
   'questionsCode'], dtype=object)
```

Expected data frame with below columns:

```
['Country', 'Survey', 'a typical day', 'a particularly good day',
   'a particularl', 'dk/refused', 'total', questionsCode'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**
Consider the sample dataframe `df`

```
cols = [
    'Country', 'Survey', 'a typical day',
    'a particularly good day', 'a particularl',
    'dk/refused', 'total',
    np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
   'questionsCode'
]

df = pd.DataFrame([range(13)], range(2), cols)
df

   Country  Survey  a typical day  a particularly good day  a particularl  dk/refused  total  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  questionsCode
0        0       1              2                        3              4           5      6    7    8    9   10   11             12
1        0       1              2                        3              4           5      6    7    8    9   10   11             12
```

---

**Solution 1**
Leverage `loc` with label based indexing

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.dropna()]

   Country  Survey  a typical day  a particularly good day  a particularl  dk/refused  total  questionsCode
0        0       1              2                        3              4           5      6             12
1        0       1              2                        3              4           5      6             12
```

---

*This would've also worked*

```
df[df.columns.dropna()]
```

---

**Solution 2**
Use Boolean indexing

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.notnull()]

   Country  Survey  a typical day  a particularly good day  a particularl  dk/refused  total  questionsCode
0        0       1              2                        3              4           5      6             12
1        0       1              2                        3              4           5      6             12
```